# Automatic scrolling using next button from key board but last field is not visible properly i need to scroll it manually to fill the field

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am using SingelChildScrollView. I have few custom textFromFields. I am using a focus node so that when I click the next button, it will focus on the current node of the field. My issue is that when i am going to the last field, which is my 6th field, which contains  **key: controller.leadFromKey6,**
is not visible properly because I use a stack for the button, so it creates a barrier for the field. I want that when I go the last field, it will scroll little bit more so that user can see it easily.
[image]

My proposed amount field is not showing properly if it scroll little bit more it can be visible easily

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:base_project/app/core/translations/translation_keys.dart';
import 'package:base_project/app/core/value/colors.dart';
import 'package:base_project/app/routes/app_routes.dart';
import 'package:base_project/app/utils/app_button.dart';
import 'package:base_project/app/utils/image_helper.dart';
import 'package:base_project/app/utils/widgets/app_text_form_field.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

import '../../utils/app_validator.dart';
import '../../utils/widgets/app_dropdown.dart';
import 'lead_infromation_controller.dart';

class LeadInformationPage extends GetView<LeadInformationController>
    with AppValidatorService {
  LeadInformationPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      bottomNavigationBar:
          Platform.isIOS ? const BottomAppBar(color: AppColors.white) : null,
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        elevation: 2,
        flexibleSpace: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.h, left: 15.w),
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Center(
            child: Row(
              children: [
                GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      Get.offAllNamed(Routes.home);
                    },
                    child: ImageHelper.getSvg("arrow_back_btn",
                        height: 15.h, width: 12.w)),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 20.w,
                ),
                Text(
                  TranslationKeys.fillUpTheLeadInformation.tr,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      fontSize: 18.sp),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          SingleChildScrollView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 16.h, left: 14.w, bottom: 16.h, right: 14.w),
            child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50.h),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Form(
                    key: controller.leadFromKey1,
                    autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                    child: AppTextFormField(
                      fieldName: TranslationKeys.fullName.tr,
                      hintText: TranslationKeys.enterYourFullName.tr,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        controller.leadPostModel.name = value.trim();
                        controller.leadFromKey1.currentState!.validate();
                      },
                      inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                        FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp("[a-z A-Z]")),
                        LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(50),
                      ],
                      validator: validateEmpty,
                      focusNode: controller.fullNameFocusNode,
                      onEditingComplete: () {
                        FocusScope.of(context)
                            .requestFocus(controller.contactInfoFocusNode);
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  Form(
                    key: controller.leadFromKey2,
                    autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
                    child: AppTextFormField(
                      fieldName: TranslationKeys.contactInformation.tr,
                      hintText: TranslationKeys.enterYourMobileNo.tr,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                        FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
                        LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(11),
                      ],
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        controller.leadPostModel.contactNumber = value.trim();
                        controller.leadFromKey2.currentState!.validate();
                      },
                      validator: validateMobileNumber,
                      focusNode: controller.contactInfoFocusNode,
                      onEditingComplete: () {
                        FocusScope.of(context)
                            .requestFocus(controller.addressFocusNode);
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  Form(
                    key: controller.leadFromKey3,
                    child: AppTextFormField(
                      fieldName: TranslationKeys.address.tr,
                      hintText: TranslationKeys.enterYourAddress.tr,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        controller.leadPostModel.address = value.trim();
                        controller.leadFromKey3.currentState!.validate();
                      },
                      validator: validateAddress,
                      /*  validator: (value) {
                        if(value!.isNotEmpty){
                          return leadValidateAddress(value);
                        }
                      },*/
                      focusNode: controller.addressFocusNode,
                      onEditingComplete: () {
                        FocusScope.of(context)
                            .requestFocus(controller.nidFocusNode);
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  Form(
                    key: controller.leadFromKey4,
                    child: AppTextFormField(
                      starMark: false,
                      fieldName: TranslationKeys.nID.tr,
                      hintText: TranslationKeys.enterYourNid.tr,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                        FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
                        LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(17),
                      ],
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        controller.leadPostModel.nid = value.trim();
                        controller.leadFromKey4.currentState!.validate();                      },
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value!.isNotEmpty) {
                          return validateNID(value);
                        }
                      },
                      focusNode: controller.nidFocusNode,
                      onEditingComplete: () {
                        FocusScope.of(context)
                            .requestFocus(controller.appDropDown);
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  Form(
                    key: controller.leadFromKey5,
                    child: Obx(() {
                      return AppDropdown(
                        controller.businessTypeList.value,
                        title: TranslationKeys.leadsBusinessType.tr,
                        validationMsg:
                            TranslationKeys.referrerCategoryValidationMsg.tr,
                        onChange: (value) {
                          controller.leadPostModel.leadBusinessTypeId =
                              value?.id;
                          controller.businessType.value = value;
                          controller.leadFromKey5.currentState!.validate();
                          FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(controller.proposedAmountFocusNode);
                        },
                        hintText: TranslationKeys.selectBusinessType.tr,
                        dropdownBackgroundColor: AppColors.backgroundColor,
                        focusNode: controller.appDropDown,
                      );
                    }),
                  ),
                  Form(
                    key: controller.leadFromKey6,
                    child: AppTextFormField(
                      fieldName: TranslationKeys.proposedLoanAmount.tr,
                      hintText: TranslationKeys.enterProposedAmount.tr,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                        LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(12),
                        AppTextFormField.decimalTextInputFormat,
                      ],
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        controller.leadPostModel.proposedLoanAmount =
                            double.tryParse(value);
                        controller.leadFromKey6.currentState!.validate();
                      },
                      validator: validateAmount,
                      focusNode: controller.proposedAmountFocusNode,
                      /*  validator: (value) {
                        if(value!.isNotEmpty){
                          return leadValidateAmount(value);
                        }
                      },*/
                    ),
                  ),
                  Obx(() {
                    return _uploadPhotoCard();
                  }),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.white,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: (Platform.isIOS &&
                          MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom > 0)
                      ? EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.h, 10.h, 10.h, 0.h)
                      : EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 10.h, left: 10.w, right: 10.w, bottom: 2.w),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: AppButton(
                          () {
                            controller.saveAsDraft();
                          },
                          TranslationKeys.submitDraft.tr,
                          fillColor:
                              AppColors.textFieldHintFont.withOpacity(0.3),
                          customStyle: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              fontSize: 18.sp,
                              fontWeight: Platform.isIOS
                                  ? FontWeight.normal
                                  : FontWeight.w800),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 10.w,
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: AppButton(
                          () {
                            controller.saveAsPending();
                          },
                          TranslationKeys.submit.tr,
                          fillColor: AppColors.submitButtonPink,
                          customStyle: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 18.sp,
                              fontWeight: Platform.isIOS
                                  ? FontWeight.normal
                                  : FontWeight.w800),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _uploadPhotoCard() {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.h, bottom: 15.h),
          padding:
              EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.h, bottom: 15.h, left: 15.w, right: 15.w),
          color: AppColors.boxColour,
          width: double.infinity,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  controller.getImageFromGallery();
                },
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: 50.h,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      ImageHelper.getSvg("uploadPhoto",
                          color: AppColors.pink, height: 24.h, width: 24.h),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 10.w,
                      ),
                      Text(TranslationKeys.updatePhoto.tr),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  controller.getImageFromCamera();
                },
                child: Container(
                  color: AppColors.boxColour,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: 50.h,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      ImageHelper.getSvg("Camera_duotone_line",
                          height: 24.h, width: 24.h),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 10.w,
                      ),
                      Text(TranslationKeys.capturePhoto.tr),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        controller.imagePath.isNotEmpty
            ? Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                  bottom: 20.h,
                ),
                padding:
                    EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, bottom: 5, left: 10.w, right: 10.w),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    border:
                        Border.all(color: AppColors.borderColor, width: 1.5.w),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.r)),
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                height: 50.h,
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.r),
                      ),
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.w),
                      height: 30.w,
                      width: 30.w,
                      child: Image.file(
                        File(controller.imagePath.toString()),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                        flex: 6, child: Text(controller.imageName.toString())),
                    const Spacer(),
                    InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        controller.imagePath.value = '';
                        controller.imageName.value = '';
                        controller.imageFile.value = File("");
                        controller.imageFile.value = File("");
                      },
                      child: Image.asset(
                        "assets/images/close_round.png",
                        width: 24.w,
                        height: 24.w,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            : const SizedBox(),
        Row(
          children: [
            ImageHelper.getSvg('info_light', height: 24.h, width: 24.w),
            SizedBox(
              width: 10.w,
            ),
            Expanded(child: Text(TranslationKeys.photoUploadHint.tr))
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
My issue is that when I go to the last field, it will increase the scroll position a little bit.

This my whole page
```

Comment: The `SingleChildScrollView` doing it's work but you buttons are on top so it's overlapping the `field`... And as i see you are using the stack to put that buttons on bottom of the screen over your form, so for that you can use the `bottomSheet` or `bottomNavigationBar` parameters of scaffold which will place the button on bottom. that can solve your problem. Or if you don't want to do it then you need to manually, put some bottom padding to the SingleChildScrollView or it's child.